# Compare a row from a executor to all the rows of other executor in spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a row in a executor which I need to compare from all other rows in different executors.

I have tried using `dataframe.collect()` but it pulls all the data into driver which eventually ends up in OOM error.

Suppose I have a date which I need to compare from other dates which are in different executor.
Input is as below

```
 Name, Date1, Date2 
A, 2019-01-01, 2019-01-23 
A, 2019-02-12, 2019-03-21
A, 2019-04-01, 2019-05-31
A, 2019-06-02, 2019-12-30 
B, 2019-01-01, 2019-01-21 
B, 2019-02-10, 2019-03-21 
B, 2019-04-01, 2019-12-31
```

I have to compare each date of Date1 from each row of Date2 and find the difference between the dates and I cant use lead or lag functions.

Expected output:

```
Name, Date1, Date2,no_of_days_diff
A, 2019-01-01, 2019-01-23,-20 
A, 2019-02-12, 2019-03-21,-11
A, 2019-04-01, 2019-05-31,-2
A, 2019-06-02, 2019-12-30, 
B, 2019-01-01, 2019-01-21,-20
B, 2019-02-10, 2019-03-21,-11
B, 2019-04-01, 2019-12-31
```

I have to subtract date2 with data1 of respective name.

Comment: Please can you explain a bit more on what basis you want to compare the rows?

Comment: Please check the updated question

Comment: Can you please specify what is your end-game? Example of input with its desired output

Comment: Seems like you are using a foreach or map, where you should be using a Join. Can you please the part of code that compares the dates?